# Symfony2 validation filters

Tags: validation, symfony, filtering

In my Symfony 2 application I need to filter input before passing it on to validation [1], however, I can't seem to find any system within Symfony to do this.

The type of filtering I looking for is e.g. to be able to filter a dash out of a specific field before validating it. E.g. users can enter `123-123` but the only accepted value is `123123`. Just as I can set up validation rules with constraints, I'm looking for something similar for filters.

[1] http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html

Answer (score 2):

[Nifr's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832745/nifr) answer is good but is missing of an important alternative that, if I understand correctly your question, seems to fit perfectly your needs.

You can use a *hook* that is pretty much an event listener: if something happens or is going to happen, it intercepts the event and redirect it to your function.

In this case, you need a **PRE_BIND** hook (is deprecated since 2.3 version, now it's called **PRE_SUBMIT**)

Read [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html) if you need help about

Answer (score 0):

Either write your [own Validation Assert](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html) to filter and then proxy the other validators for this purpose ...

... or one or multiple [Regex Asserts](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Regex.html).

... or use a [**DataTransformer**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) to transform/filter the input.

With the DataTransformer involved you could aswell consider creating a new FieldType which renders two inputs with a seperator like the *date* form-field does. ( if not not used with `widget => single_text` )